# Mismatched numpy versions in a venv on a running cluster with EMR notebooks

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, numpy, amazon-emr

Trying to upgrade the `numpy` version on a running cluster with EMR notebooks.

My conf file is:

```
%%configure -f
{ "conf":{
          "spark.pyspark.python": "python3",
          "spark.pyspark.virtualenv.enabled": "true",
          "spark.pyspark.virtualenv.type":"native",
          "spark.pyspark.virtualenv.bin.path":"/usr/bin/virtualenv",
          "driverMemory": "6000M"
         }
}
```

and my `sc.list_packages()` is:

```
Package                    Version
-------------------------- ---------
absl-py                    0.8.1
astor                      0.8.0
beautifulsoup4             4.8.1
bleach                     3.1.0
blis                       0.7.7
boto                       2.49.0
boto3                      1.21.37
botocore                   1.24.37
catalogue                  2.0.7
certifi                    2021.10.8
charset-normalizer         2.0.12
click                      8.0.4
contextvars                2.4
cycler                     0.11.0
cymem                      2.0.6
dataclasses                0.8
en-core-web-sm             3.2.0
funcsigs                   1.0.2
gast                       0.3.2
google-pasta               0.1.7
grpcio                     1.24.3
html5lib                   1.0.1
idna                       3.3
immutables                 0.17
importlib-metadata         4.8.3
importlib-resources        5.4.0
Jinja2                     3.0.3
jmespath                   0.9.4
joblib                     1.1.0
Keras-Applications         1.0.6
Keras-Preprocessing        1.0.5
kiwisolver                 1.3.1
langcodes                  3.3.0
lxml                       4.4.2
Markdown                   3.1.1
MarkupSafe                 2.0.1
matplotlib                 3.3.4
murmurhash                 1.0.6
mysqlclient                1.4.6
nltk                       3.6.7
nose                       1.3.4
numpy                      1.19.5
packaging                  21.3
pandas                     1.1.5
pathy                      0.6.1
Pillow                     8.4.0
pip                        21.3.1
preshed                    3.0.6
protobuf                   3.10.0
py-dateutil                2.2
pydantic                   1.8.2
pyparsing                  3.0.8
python-dateutil            2.8.2
python36-sagemaker-pyspark 1.2.6
pytz                       2019.3
PyYAML                     3.11
regex                      2022.3.15
requests                   2.27.1
s3transfer                 0.5.2
scikit-learn               0.24.2
scipy                      1.5.4
seaborn                    0.11.2
setuptools                 59.6.0
six                        1.13.0
smart-open                 5.2.1
soupsieve                  1.9.5
spacy                      3.2.4
spacy-legacy               3.0.9
spacy-loggers              1.0.2
spacy-lookups-data         1.0.3
srsly                      2.4.2
tensorboard                1.14.0
tensorflow                 1.14.0
tensorflow-estimator       1.14.0
termcolor                  1.1.0
thinc                      8.0.15
threadpoolctl              3.1.0
tqdm                       4.64.0
typer                      0.4.1
typing-extensions          3.10.0.2
urllib3                    1.26.9
wasabi                     0.9.1
webencodings               0.5.1
Werkzeug                   0.16.0
wheel                      0.37.1
windmill                   1.6
wrapt                      1.11.2
zipp                       3.6.0
```

and it is clear that I have `numpy 1.19.5` installed. However when I import numpy I get:

[image]

How do I get the cluster to point to the correct library? Keeping in mind I do not have admin rights on the cluster. Thanks

Comment: Also if you're submitting jobs in client mode and using a virtualenv already, make sure to activate it first, not required in cluster mode.

Comment: thanks @jbaranski I did activate it prior to the running the code.

Admin have made some changes to the cluster so will see if that resolved the issue